# Analogue of the original Birch–Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture for abelian varieties

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, l-functions, birch-swinnerton-dyer

$\newcommand{\Q}{\Bbb Q}
\newcommand{\N}{\Bbb N}
\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb R}
\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z}
\newcommand{\C}{\Bbb C}
\newcommand{\F}{\Bbb F}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}
$
Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a number field $F$.
It is expected that the $L$-function of $A$ has analytic continuation to $\Bbb C$ and satisfies a functional equation relating $s$ to $2-s$. In that setting, the (generalized) Birch–Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture states that
$$\mathrm{ord}_{s=1}(L(A_{/F},s)) = \mathrm{rk}_{\Z}(A(F)) =: r.$$

Originally, the conjecture for an *elliptic curve* $E$ over $\Q$ was
$$\exists C>0,\quad 
\prod_{p \leq x} \dfrac{|E(\F_p)|}{p}   \sim  C \;\mathrm{log}(x)^r  
\qquad (x \to \infty).$$

> My question is to know what is the analogue of the original conjecture, in the framework of abelian varieties over number fields.

My first guess would to replace to LHS by 
$$\prod_{N(\p) \leq x} L_{\p}(A_{/F}, N(\p)^{-1}),$$ where $L_{\p}(A_{/F},s)$ is the local factor of the L-function of $A$ at $\p$.
But I'm not sure what the RHS should be. Typically, how does it depend on the dimension of $A$ or on the degree of the number field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}$By Theorem 6.3 of [this paper by Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/articles/eulerprod.pdf), strong conjectures about $L(A,s)$ (stronger than GRH for this $L$-function, but still "believable"), imply that

$$
\prod_{N\p\le x}L_{\p}(A,N\p^{-1}) \sim C (\log x)^r
$$
where $r$ is the order of vanishing at $s=1$, which by the usual BSD should be the rank of $A(K)$.

See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239653/clarification-on-the-weak-bsd-conjecture) about the relation between the original and the modern formulation of BSD.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To apply theorem 5.11, I would need to check hypothesis (5.7), wouldn't I? How could I check it (assuming GRH, possibly...)?

Comment: @Watson Sorry, I quoted the wrong theorem!

Comment: Moreover, do you know whether the constant $C$ depend on $A$ (in particular of $\mathrm{dim}(A)$)?

Comment: @Watson Konrad's paper also relates $C$ to the leading term, at $s=1$: this is Theorem 5.11. For the BSD formula for the leading term, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181758/is-there-an-analog-of-the-birch-swinnerton-dyer-conjecture-for-abelian-varieties)

Comment: @Watson I want to point out that the mismatch between the coefficient in the (plausible but unproved!) asymptotic estimate for partial Euler products at the normalized central point $s=1/2$ and the leading Taylor coefficient of the $L$-function at that point is already appearing in the case of Hecke $L$-functions $s=1/2$: see Corollary  5.5 and Corollary 5.6. See Example 5.8 for some data in the case of one Dirichlet $L$-function.